Customizing numbering on environment with optional argument
I am not sure if this is considered bad practice so please let me know if it is. I have an environment I use form homework problems
\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}
{\topsep}{\topsep}{\normalfont}{}{\normalsize\bfseries}{}{0em}
{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2.}\ }
\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{prob}{Problem}

Usually my problems are sequential so occasionally using the \setcounter command has not been an issue, but recently I have had fewer sequential problems. What I would  like is an optional argument in my prob environment which would automatically update the counter. I.e. if the counter was previously set to 6 \begin{prob}... would generate "Problem 7" but \begin{prob}[9]... would generate "Problem 9" and update the counter to continue from there, so \begin{prob}[9]... \begin{prob}... would make "Problem 9... Problem 10". I hope this is clear.
Thank you!!
I use the package amsthm.

Please advise if you use a package such as amsthm or ntheorem.
